# Module export and import of generic types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I usually write a JavaScript/TypeScript module as follows:

```
const obj = (() => {

  const F = <A>(x: A) => x;
  const G = "bar";

  type F<A> = A; // can be more complicated than F definition

  return { F };

})();

const F = obj.F;

export { F }
```

In this manner, it's clear what objects are to be exported; however, the problem is you cannot refer the `F<A>` here.

The only way I know and currently I'm doing is to move it to the top level of the module:

```
const obj = (() => {

  const F = <A>(x: A) => x;
  const G = "bar";

  return { F };

})();

type F<A> = A; // can be more complicated than F definition

const F = obj.F;

export { F }
```

I am not comfortable to do this, is there any smart way? Thanks!